# How to change form field attribute in the view?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model form containing four fields, by default only one field is active waiting for the user input.

```
class SaleOrderInvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = SaleOrderInvoice
     fields = (
      'supplier',
      'sale_order',
      'invoice_number',
      'invoice_date',
      )
     widgets={
      'supplier':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
      'sale_order':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'disabled':'disabled'}),
      'invoice_number':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'disabled':'disabled'}),
      'invoice_date':forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'date','disabled':'disabled'}),
        }
```

Based on the user selection of the first input, the rest of the form is loaded via AJAX. Now in the view, after necessary filtering, I want to swtich the disabled form fields to enabled and the enabled to disabled. I have tried the following but with no luck.

```
form = SaleOrderInvoiceForm()
form.fields['supplier'].disabled = True
form.fields['sale_order'].disabled = False
form.fields['invoice_number'].disabled = False
form.fields['invoice_date'].disabled = False
```

It neither raises any exceptions nor it works as desired.
can anyone suggest a way forward with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it appears the disabled attribute cannot be reset back to False, it can however `pop` out.

```
    form.fields['supplier'].disabled = 'disabled'
    form.fields['sale_order'].widget.attrs.pop('disabled')
    form.fields['invoice_number'].widget.attrs.pop('disabled')
    form.fields['invoice_date'].widget.attrs.pop('disabled')
```

Comment: this code can only change disabled, I wanted to change to `readonly`,  for that  I needed ```form.fields['invoice_number'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = 'readonly'```